# Upate query with where clause in Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

its my first question here on this site. 
well i have a problem regarding update query.

```
  ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
  args.put("j_id", str);

  db.update(TABLE_NAME2, args, null, null);
```

i just want to add "where" clause into it.

like

```
   UPDATE TABLE_NAME2
   SET j_id=str
   WHERE j_id = '-1'
```

So what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `null` as the third argument, you can pass the `WHERE`-clause. [See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

---

In your case, this would look like this:

```
String value = "-1"; // Or something else
String column = "j_id"; // The Column for the WHERE-clause
db.update(TABLE_NAME2, args, column+" = ?", new String[]{value});
```

You should always use the prepared-statement syntax. Thus, you don't actually add the value for the `WHERE`-clause in the String but use the fourth argument which takes a String-array to replace the `?` in the `WHERE`-query-string.

The first element of the String-array is replaced with the first `?` in the query-string and so on. So in the end, this creates a WHERE-clause like this:

```
WHERE j_id = '-1'
```

Comment: yeah i tried but it did not work. I am new at 'Sqlite'. can you please write a line of Syntax? Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: I added this to my original answer.

Comment: So, click the "up"-button and tick the green tick :D